# How postgresql determines the bind parameter values and their type?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I've created a table and running the query as shown in below snippet. And the table has different column with different types including timestamp , real , bigint , array etc

**Question**

1. When am running the query i passed the bind arguments for bigint , double precision as strings in where clause. How does sql compares / converts these string into real types while fetching the data ?
2. Can i safely assume that passing string args as bind values in where clause irrespective of column type would yield right results?

```
CREATE TABLE common
(
    time timestamp(3) without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    duration_millis bigint,
    customer_name text, 
    active_customers integer, 
    inactive_customers bigint,
    paid_accounts_rating double precision,
    customer_rating real,
    attr_bool boolean,
    attr_bytes bytea,
    attr_array text[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
);


SELECT * FROM common WHERE (customer_name = 'test' and active_customers>='32' and inactive_customers >= '22') OR
    (customer_name = 'test2' and active_customers>='32' and inactive_customers = '22' and paid_accounts_rating < '0.6456') ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple test case shows that PostgreSQL stores the prepared statements with information about parameters types and is doing parameter conversion at execution time:

```
create table t (x int, y text);
CREATE TABLE
insert into t values(32, 'abc');
INSERT 0 1
prepare s1 as select * from t where x=$1;
PREPARE
select name, statement, parameter_types from pg_prepared_statements;
 name |                 statement                 | parameter_types 
------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------
 s1   | prepare s1 as select * from t where x=$1; | {integer}
(1 row)

execute s1(32);
 x  |  y  
----+-----
 32 | abc
(1 row)

execute s1('32');
 x  |  y  
----+-----
 32 | abc
(1 row)
```

It must be documented somewhere but I didn't find it.